# Add user to group vs create group in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to clarify the difference between “add user to group“ and “create a new group“ in Azure.

Someone said, we can do any of this in MS Azure. I don’t know much about Azure infra.

What is the difference between these two? Is it about new AD group or add to existing AD group? If so, what is the benefit of creating a new group or adding ID into a existing group? Can I access an existing subscription creating new group as other groups are accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. These are the two ways. The individual account can be added as well we can create a group. One person can be group owner, later group owner can add other members, this looking like Microsoft recommendation. To access existing subscription multiple groups can be created. Multiple groups can have different types of control permission to the subscription based on group type.

Answer (score -1):

The question itself has the answer. If you already have a group with defined roles policies which are necessary for the group you just need to add the users to the existing group.

If you don't have a group with the defined policies and roles then you need to create a new group and add the users to that group.

Comment: why down vote? may be i misunderstood the question.